# android : Can we implement a single dialog showing error, if multiple activities in a flow crashes?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

- When a single activity crashes, all the activities in flow crashes.
- As all activities crash, each generates its own error dialog, so can we have a single dialog for all crashes?
- Try catch is already implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a singleton static final object to handle all your diablog boxes across all your activities.  One such singleton object is the application object, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html, but you don't have to use that one if you don't want to.

Also, you have to make sure that try/catch is implemented absolutely everywhere, wherever the android operating system makes calls into your app code.  I'll find that I've got try/catch in most places in my code, but somehow when I'm trying to develop quickly I accidentally miss a few places and of course they're the ones that end up causing me a problem!

Comment: Thanks!!
Will check the code again and implement the Try/Catch block if i missed somewhere